# Is there any difference in There exist and For some?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, notation, quantifiers

When the backwards E notation $\exists$ is shown I've been told that it can mean There exist but I've also been told that it could mean For some. Is there a difference between one or the other? Do I have to use one for a certain circumstance?

Comment: Yes, they are the same, just as "for all" and "for every" and "for each" mean $\forall$.

Comment: They are logically equivalent, but the English language creates a difference, namely that "there exists" is followed by "such that", while "for some" isn't. Thus "there exists $x$ **such that** $P(x)$" but "for some $x$, $P(x)$."  In this respect, the mathematical symbol $\exists$ behaves like "for some". So one should write "$\exists x\,P(x)$" without any extra stuff like "s.t." or $\ni$ after $\exists x$.

Comment: "There exists an object where some property is true"  .... "The property is true for some object" ..... "The property is true for some existing object".... Yeah, they all sound the same to me.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, is the "such that" semantically important? Wouldn't it be just part of the syntax, without any effect on the meaning? In english, we say "$x$ is equal to $y$", but in mathematical notation, this is "$x = y$", where "$=$" is the *equal* sign, not the "is equal to" sign. Where did the "is ... to" go? "is ... to" is just part of the english syntax. From the semantic point of view, we don't need worry about it.

Comment: @JoãoJúnior I agree that "such that", like "is ... to", is just part of English syntax. And I add that one should not import them into mathematical symbolism.  That is, one should not write "$\exists x\text{ such that }P(x)$, just as one should not write "$x\text{ is }=\text{ to }y$."

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Logically, they are the same. The sentences "There is $x$ such that $P(x)$" and "$P(x)$ for some $x$" are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Further to the existing comments and answer, do also be aware of the issue of [hanging quantifiers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2721785/21813): to prevent [scope ambiguities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510219/what-is-the-logical-interpretation-of-this-set), avoid writing "for some" behind the predicate when there are multiple quantifiers. (This issue doesn't exist when you use "there exists" instead.)

For example, do write

- for some $x,$ for all $y, P(x,y)$

instead of any of the following, each of which is ambiguous:

- for all $y, P(x,y)$ for some $x$
- $P(x,y)$ for all $y$ for some $x$
- $P(x,y)$ for some $x$ for all $y.$

Synonyms for "there exists… such that" include:

1. for some
2. there is some … such that
3. there is a … such that
4. there is at least one … such that

Comment: P.S. For variation, "such that" = "for which".