# Nested quantifiers for $y < x^2$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

1. $∀x ∃y P(x, y)$

   For every $x$ there exists a $y…$

   This is true, because for every number $x$ there exists at least one number $y$ for the statement to be true. For example, we can choose $x=100$ and $y =10.$
2. $∀y ∃x P(x, y)$

   ?
3. $∃x ∀y P(x, y)$

   There exists a $x$ (such that) for every $y…,$

   This is true, we can increment $x$ and $y$ to infinite, and every
   time the statement will stay true. If we set an end to the infinite
   and give the largest number possible to $x,$ that number will hold
   true for any possible $y.$
4. $∃y ∀ x P(x, y)$

   There exists a $y$ (such that) for every $x…,$ means that there is a
   $y$ that is less than $x^2$ for every possible $x.$ This is true
   because we can give $y$ a negative value, whatever value we will
   give $x$ will still be more than any negative value because it is
   quadratic.

Is this how you correctly understand quantifiers? Or am I understanding wrongly?

Comment: Forgot to add that x and y are REAL numbers

Comment: "For example, we can choose $x=100$ and $y=10$." That doesn't show $\forall x\ \exists y$ but only $\exists x\ \exists y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> P.S. Forgot to add that x and y are REAL numbers

It isn't necessary to specify this, since complex numbers cannot be ordered anyway.

> 1. $∀x ∃y P(x, y)$
>
>    For every $x$ there exists a $y…$
>
>    This is true, because...

Yes.

> 2. $∀y ∃x P(x, y)$

This is true, because no matter what $y$ is, there is always some $x$ whose square is bigger, since $\mathbb R$ has no upper bound.

> 3. $∃x ∀y P(x, y)$
>
> There exists a $x$ (such that) for every $y…,$
>
> This is true, we can increment $x$ and $y$ to infinite, and every time the statement will stay true. If we ***set an end to the infinite*** and give the largest number possible to $x,$ that number will hold true for any possible $y.$

Proposition $3$ is false, because no such $x$ exists, precisely because we *cannot* "set an end to the infinite".

> 4. $∃y ∀ x P(x, y)$
>
> There exists a $y$ (such that) for every $x…,$ means that the is a
> $y$ that is less than $x^2$ for every possible $x.$ This is true
> because...

Yes. But do be careful though: "there is a $y$ that is less than $x^2$ for every possible $x$" is ambiguous (it contains a [hanging quantifier](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4207357/21813)), and can be interpreted either as $∃y ∀x P(x, y)$ or $∀x ∃y P(x, y).$

Comment: Thank you for this Answer, would it help if I draw the function? Does the visual help?

Comment: @ili $P(x,y)$ is satisfied everywhere underneath the parabola; I feel that sketching this region isn't terribly useful, since your trouble is not with understanding that simple inequality, but with getting used to parsing first-order-logic sentences (in particular, discerning the difference in meaning when quantifiers switch order).

Comment: @ili As for md2perpe's comment, I wouldn't worry too much about his (not incorrect) point, since the important thing is that you *do* actually understand proposition $(1)$ and were merely citing an example, albeit in a way that seemed like you were explaining a different proposition.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding and examples for your first and last sentence sounds right.

As for the sentence $\forall y \exists x P(x, y)$ in your case, it reads "for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ there's some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y<x^2$" which is certainly true as there's no upper bound of the term $x^2$.

As for the sentence $\exists x \forall y P(x, y)$ in your case, it reads "there's some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ it's the case that $y<x^2$" which is clearly false since if you happens to find such $x$, you can always find a positive $y>x^2$.

In conclusion order matters for mixed quantifiers with different types...

Comment: Thank you for this Answer, would it help if I draw the function? Does the visual help?

Comment: @ili Yes it always does no harm... You can directly visualize above conclusions easily for your example with the right shaded region in your graph though I guess translated English sentence should be good enough here.

Comment: The statement I give for ∀x ∃y P(x, y), doesn't that translate to ∃x ∃y P(x, y), since I am not stating an arbitrary x?

Comment: @ili ∀x ∃y P(x, y) has certainly different meanings than ∃x ∃y P(x, y) from their obvious syntactic difference, your above sentence 1. is translated correctly by your own effort. If we want to translate ∃x ∃y P(x, y) for your case, then it should read as "There's some x and y such that x is less than the square of y" which is much weaker than ∀x ∃y P(x, y) . So in general you can prove rigorously ∀x ∃y P(x, y) $\to$ ∃x ∃y P(x, y) if you've learned some mathematical logic.

Comment: Thank you for the help