# Prove that $∀x∀y(P(x, y) → ¬P(y, x)),∀x∃yP(x, y)$ can be deduced to $¬∃v∀zP(z, v)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, predicate-logic

Using natural deduction rules prove the statement:

$∀x∀y(P(x, y) → ¬P(y, x)),∀x∃yP(x, y)$ can be deduced to $¬∃v∀zP(z, v)$

I don't want to be given an answer, but a hint on how to start because I am stuck for a long time on this problem not knowing how to start efficiently.

Comment: Well, I don't know predicate logic rules,  but in English it's pretty clear.  The first premise is that $P$ is anti-symmetric,  the second is that everything (In your universe of discourse) is in the domain of $P$.   From that they want you to conclude that there's nothing that could be a universal second element of $P$, which is clear because from statement 2, the reverse order pair would exist for one element, and statement 1 would say that can't happen.   Can you convert that into your rules?

Answer (score -1):

Obviously here you can use proof by negation together with formal inference rules regarding quantifiers allowed in your system, and then a useful hint would be the predicate $P$ here can be interpreted as a strict partial order and thus $∃v∀zP(z,v)$ must be false when $z=v$, which is certainly an unavoidable special case for $∃v∀zP(z,v)$, while the given premise $∀x∃yP(x,y)$ can avoid such special case...

Comment: why must the predicate be false for $z=v$? What if it handles the special case and is true?

Comment: @user737163 pls note $∃v∀zP(z,v)$ is a universal condition stronger than $∀x∃yP(x,y)$, and [order of mixed quantifiers matters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4278522/nested-quantifiers-for-y-x2/4278607#4278607). If you use natural number N with its usual < binary relation (strict partial order) as a model, then clearly when $z=v$, the assumed conclusion $∃v∀zP(z,v)$ must be false, thus a contradiction. And the previous 2 premises are used to formally prove this strict partial order property. Since you stated you only need hint, I think this is a critical one. Hope you now "see" it..