# Negating "There is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>0~$ for all $x>0$"

Tags: logic

I have to make the negation of the following sentence.

> There is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>\epsilon~$  for all $x>0$.

Here is my attempt:

> For each $\epsilon>0$, $f(x)\leq \epsilon~$ for some $x>0$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that's the correct answer.

Comment: Well done, the correct negation.

Comment: It is best not to put quantifiers both before and after.  Two possible meanings:   
$$\text{There is some $\epsilon>0$ such that ($f(x)>0~$ for all $x>0$)}$$   
$$\text{(There is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>0~$) for all $x>0$}$$

Comment: Elaborating on GEdgar’s comment: [hanging quantifiers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4207357/21813). Your translation is so correct that it even preserves the ambiguity of the given sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. The initial statement reads
$$\exists \varepsilon >0,\  \forall x>0,\  f(x)>0. $$
When negated, we switch the quantifiers and negate the statement $f(x)>0$. So
$$ \forall \varepsilon >0,\ \exists x>0,\ f(x)\leqslant 0. $$

---

Note that the statment does not explicitly make use of $\varepsilon$ anywhere, though. Could replace $f(x)>0$ with $f(x)\geqslant\varepsilon$, for instance.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected